# Get qty sold, cost price and the selling price of a product in magento using Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9

I would like to seek help on my problem. I have a query in which it pull data (SKU, Product Name and Product Description) from the database. I'm doing this as I'm trying to create an extension of a some kind of reporting tool, although it is just for personal use for now.

What I need is the following:

**SKU,
Product Name,
Product description,**
Quantity sold,
Cost Price,
Selling Price

Those in bold, I already managed to pull it from the dbase itself. I would like to seek any assistance to pull the 3 remaining. Qty sold is the sum of all complete orders of that product.

Here's my code that I managed to use so far.

```
    SELECT 
    `e`.`sku`, 
    IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`,
    IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description`

FROM 
   `mgob_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
    INNER JOIN 
         `mgob_catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` 
               ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `mgob_eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `mgob_eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `mgob_catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` 
               ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `mgob_eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `mgob_eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) 
    INNER JOIN 
         `mgob_catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` 
               ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `mgob_eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `mgob_eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `mgob_catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` 
               ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `mgob_eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `mgob_eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1) "
```

Comment: Do you got an ERD of your database?

Comment: Schema? I have one of those Sir.

Comment: Well can you add the ERD to the post out of the tables you need it from?